# Two dataframe merge with same data in 'choices.text' row and 'Survey_Question_Answer '

Tags: python, django, dataframe

[1st data frame image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0131.png)   **my first data frame is**

```
df_chart_data_table=SurveyResponseDetails.objects.values('Survey_Question_Answer','Survey_Question_No').order_by('Survey_Question_No').filter(Survey_Id='1H2711202014572742').annotate(Survey_Question_Answer_count=Count('Survey_Question_Answer'))
data = list(df_chart_data_table.values_list('Survey_Question_Answer_count', flat=True))
tableanswer=pd.DataFrame(df_chart_data_table)
totalanswer = tableanswer.to_html()
```

**my second dataframe**

```
jsondata=SurveyMaster.objects.all().filter(survey_id='1H2711202014572742')
    passvalue = jsondata.values('survey_json_design')
    qs_json = pd.DataFrame(passvalue)
    json_normalize = pd.json_normalize(qs_json\['survey_json_design'\], record_path=\['pages','elements'\])
    table_normalize=flat_table.normalize(json_normalize, expand_dicts=False, expand_lists=True)
    drop_table=table_normalize.drop(\['choices.value','isRequired'\], axis = 1)
    drop_table.rename(columns = {'title':'Survey_Question_Desc'}, inplace = True) 

    final_table= drop_table.to_html()
```

As you can see 1st image is my 1st dataframe
2nd image is my 2nd data frame
and 3rd is which i have tried to using concat() but you can see choices.tex is different from Survey_question_answer so i want same data as choices.text.

```
 concate = pd.concat([tableanswer, table_normalize], axis=1, sort=False)
    
    frame=pd.DataFrame(concate)

    drop_table=frame.drop(['choices.value','isRequired','index','name','type'], axis = 1)
    drop_table = frame[['index','Survey_Question_No', 'title','choices.text','Survey_Question_Answer','Survey_Question_Answer_count']]
    #drop_table.rename(columns = {'title':'Survey_Question_Desc'}, inplace = True) 
    table=drop_table.to_html()
```